# Stuck on Black Screen after Install 20.04

Tags: boot, system-installation

finally switching or trying to switch to Ubuntu on one of my machines, and am having problems getting the thing to actually work.

I created a bootable usb on my Win10 pc, and "installed" 20.04 on my other pc. However, when it tells you to restart to complete installation, the pc simply hangs on boot on a black screen. The bios posts, so it's doing something, but doesn't go beyond the black screen.

I've looked around, and found a thread about running boot-repair, which I did. Here is the pastebin link to what the system told me: http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/BWNsbmBv49/

Any and all suggestions would be much appreciated. TIA.

---

System:

- Mobo: Asrock x370 Killer Sli/ac
- CPU: Ryzen 7 1700
- RAM: 32gb
- GPU: Sapphire RX580
- Storage 1: 250gb nvme (Samsung 970) - boot drive
- Storage 2: 250gb ssd (Crucial MX)
- Storage 3: 4tb hdd (WD)
- Display: Generic HDMI External Display